# How to attach UE4 project to CV?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I've got an Unreal engine project and I would like to show it in my CV. However, I don't quite understand which files do I need to upload to google disc, as the project itself is rather huge

Answer (score 0):

You could package the project as a standalone, executable application. This will be much smaller than your whole UE4 project (even before you zip it up, which you'll want to do anyway of course) and anyone receiving it would be able to run it without having to install anything additional.

Have a look here: [Packaging Projects](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Basics/Projects/Packaging/index.html)